# Check for two values in same row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have retrieved some values using powerquery, its essential records from track and field meets. They are structured like this:

```
Meet | Result | Name
WC       10      John
NC       11      John
DC       12      Evan
```

So I need to check if any row contains both "John" and "WC". Is this possible?

Edit:

Will it also be possible to check if the row contains "John", while the other cell in the row has text  "WC", so it can be "WC America" and still be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a countif statement.

=countif is structured like this:

=countif(range1, condition1, range2, condition2, .... etc

Assuming "Meet" is in cell A1 use this:

```
=countif(A:A,"WC",C:C,"John")
```

**Update per your comment**

If you want to check if a cell contains WC instead then use a formula like this one below:

```
={SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND("WC",A:A))=FALSE,1,0))}
```

In order to get the curly brackets, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you enter the formula.

To extend this formula to include searching for "John" again do the following:

```
={SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND("WC",A:A))=FALSE,IF(C:C = "John",1,0),0))}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick request - is it possible to check if the cell contains "WC" rather than being equal?

Comment: Per your edit: Sorry, I was unclear, I was wondering if I could do the same check, but catch cases where the cell could contain "WC something" or "WC something else" rather than just specifically WC.

Comment: @bjornasm Take a look at my next edit. I think that has what you want exactly

Comment: Sorry, But I get an error with both your suggestions, "To many arguments" for the countif, then just a problem with the last one. Have you tried this in excel?

Comment: yes. I literally copy and pasted it

Comment: Double check that your parenthesis make sense and are in the right places.

Answer (score 3):

To correct Eric F's comment, for multiple conditions, he should use "countifs" with an s at the end for plural, not "countif" alone.
Correction:

```
=countifs(A:A,"WC",C:C,"John")
```