# Return value in column based on value of two rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a way to check if two cells in each row have a specific value, and if so, return the value in column D within that row.

It's a little difficult to explain, but I'm essentially doing what is happening here: [Check for two values in same row in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/999799/check-for-two-values-in-same-row-in-excel)

For the rows that contain the values "x" and "y", I'd like to return the value located in the same row but one column over, without specifying a specific cell. Right now, I can return the value but I must specify a cell. Is there a way to have excel determine the cells that match that criteria?

Is there a formula that will look for criteria within a specific row and a specific column to get the result?

Any help would be great!

Comment: If you had to search for a match by one column you could use the VLOOKUP() function. But you need to search the matched row by 2 columns. The easiest way is to create additional 'helper' column (maybe hidden) which concatenates the values from these 2 columns using intermediate separator which is absent in these columns values with guarantee, and then VLOOKUP by this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An Array (CSE) formula wrapped with `Index and Match` solves the issue.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `I15`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(J$10:J$12,MATCH(1,("AC"=I$10:I$12)*("John"=K$10:K$12),0)),"")}
  ```

---

*If you want to make the formula dynamic the put criteria in any two cells and use cell reference instead of value in the formula.*

[image]

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX(J$10:J$12,MATCH(1,($K$8=I$10:I$12)*($L$8=K$10:K$12),0)),"")}
```

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

*Adjust cell references & criteria in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @ Andrew ,, keep asking ☺